# How to detect touch on empty ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have an empty listView and I want to detect when user click on this empty listView, but I cannot figure out how to do this a good way.

setOnClickListener is not supported for ListView and setOnItemClickListener can only handle items but my list is empty.

Comment: You can have a transparent View on top of the ListView Add a click listener to it. Make it visible only then the ListView is empty.  There might be another way but that's the simple/first thing I thought about.

Comment: have you tried to add a touchListener to listview? also in nowaday you should use recyclerview instead of listview